# Push and Pop operations for implementing 2 stacks in one array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, stack

Need to explain how to implement two stacks in one array A[1..n] in such a way that neither stack overflows unless the total number elements in both stacks together is n

**My Approach:**

I have decided to call the stacks first and second.  Next I set, first.top = 0 and second.top = n + 1. Essentially, stack first uses the first part of the array and stack second uses the last part of the array. In stack first, the top is the rightmost element of first. In stack second, the top is the leftmost element of second

**Is there something wrong with it? or does this not suffice?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yikes. This looks too complicated. It doesn't make sense to call the stacks by different names because they inhabit the same array.

A more readable approach is to describe the stacks (I'll use C, but take your pick) as the array and two stack pointers:

```
typedef struct {
  ELEMENT elt[MAX_ELEMENTS];
  int sp_a, sp_b;
} TWO_STACKS;
```

Initialize by setting `.sp_a = .sp_b = 0.`

Now,

```
void push_a(TWO_STACKS *stks, ELEMENT elt) {
  check_full(stks);
  stks->elt[stks->sp_a++] = elt;
}
```

and

```
void push_b(TWO_STACKS *stks, ELEMENT elt) {
  check_full(stks);
  stks->elt[MAX_ELEMENTS - ++stks->sp_b] = elt;
}
```

Similarly

```
ELEMENT pop_a(TWO_STACKS *stks) {
  return stks->elt[--stks->sp_a];
}
```

and

```
ELEMENT pop_b(TWO_STACKS *stks) {
  return stks[MAX_ELEMENTS - stks->sp_b--];
}
```

`check_full` just decides whether the sum of stack pointers (which coincidentally equals the number of elements in each stack) fills the array:

```
void check_full(TWO_STACKS *stks) {
  if (stks-> sp_a + stks->sp_b >= MAX_ELEMENTS)
    // Danger Will Robinson!! Do something like exit(42);
}
```